# JS comparison two arrays (Tag filter)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to do tag filter for my project with React. I have models and activeTag.

models:

```
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test Model",
    ...
    "user_tags": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "cemreTest"
        }
    ],
    ...
},
```

activeTags:

```
[1,3]
```

I need to models which is filtered according to activeTags. I tried like these;

```
this.state.models.filter(item => item.user_tags.map(t =>  t.id) == 1).map(...)
```

This code it works.. But I need to put activeTags array instead of "1"

Like this;

```
this.state.models.filter(item => item.user_tags.map(t =>  t.id) == this.state.activeTag.map(at => at.id)).map(...)
```

How can I solve it ? Shortly, I want to filter multi values like a basic tag filters.

Comment: Why not `this.state.models.filter(item=>activetags.includes(item.id))`?

Comment: No, you used item.id but I need item.user_tags.id .So, I need to extra map() to get id. Problem is exactly here.

Comment: then this will work: `.filter(item=>item.user_tags.some(ut=>activetags.includes(ut.id)));`

Comment: I tried to test like this;
`item.user_tags.some(at => [1,3].includes(at.id))`
but it didn't work.

Comment: We need actual data to test then. That code works given the data you've provided - I'm highly confident in that. As is very frequently the case, when a [example] is actually produced - oh, the data looks different now. Either post the data your are parsing or produce a [example].

Comment: I don't know how you are always right but it's work now :) I'm sorry for my mistakes. Thank you for your example which is contain some().

Comment: glad you got it sorted.